# Apple Developer Program - Cosas a tomar en cuenta

Tags: swift, certificado-apple

Actualmente me veo en la necesidad de crear una cuenta como desarrollador de apple para poder obtener ciertos certificados y liberar muchas restricciones.

Este certificado es principalmente para poder desarrollar por completo algunas aplicaciones y lanzarlas a la tienda, estas aplicaciones son propiedad de la empresa para la que trabajo,

Mis dudas son: 
Que cosas debo tener en cuenta a la hora de pagar por una cuenta de desarrollador? 
Para que pais o region deberia registrar mi cuenta? 
Deberia ser individual o como empresa?

El pais en donde vivo es Honduras, anteriormente intente registrarme en el programa de desarrolladores usando mi region pero lastimosamente no me aparecia la opcion disponible, entonces estoy en duda si deberia usar "Estados Unidos" o algun otro pais para registrar por completo la cuenta y no se si eso podria tener complicaciones a futuro.

Agradezco cualquier aporte para poder despejar mis dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear tu cuenta en cualquier país siempre y cuando tengas una dirección y una tarjeta de crédito que acepte cargos internacionales. A tener en cuenta es la facturación que se hará en ese país.

Si eres un desarrollador que hará desarrollos propios o para empresas y piensas publicar a tu nombre, elige la cuenta individual.

Si tienes un equipo de desarrollo, no te digo que no se pueda con la individual pero es más cómodo la cuenta de Empresa, teniendo mas usuarios, roles, etc.